# Postgres locks monitoring with relname(table name)

Tags: postgresql, locks

I need to track locks. Following query working OK, but I also need `relname`(table name) which is been blocked and I have no clue how to attach it to this.

```
SELECT blocked_locks.pid     AS blocked_pid,
         blocked_activity.usename  AS blocked_user,
         blocking_locks.pid     AS blocking_pid,
         blocking_activity.usename AS blocking_user,
         blocked_activity.query    AS blocked_statement,
         blocking_activity.query   AS current_statement_in_blocking_process
   FROM  pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocked_locks
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocked_activity  ON blocked_activity.pid = blocked_locks.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocking_locks 
        ON blocking_locks.locktype = blocked_locks.locktype
        AND blocking_locks.database IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.database
        AND blocking_locks.relation IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.relation
        AND blocking_locks.page IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.page
        AND blocking_locks.tuple IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.tuple
        AND blocking_locks.virtualxid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.virtualxid
        AND blocking_locks.transactionid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.transactionid
        AND blocking_locks.classid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.classid
        AND blocking_locks.objid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objid
        AND blocking_locks.objsubid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objsubid
        AND blocking_locks.pid != blocked_locks.pid

    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocking_activity ON blocking_activity.pid = blocking_locks.pid
   WHERE NOT blocked_locks.granted;
```

Tried to join pg_class but with no success

Also i tried something like this
But i don't really know if this is a proper solution

```
SELECT 
a.datname, 
c.relname, 
a.query, 
FROM  pg_stat_activity a 
JOIN pg_locks l ON l.pid = a.pid 
JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = l.relation 
WHERE (l.GRANTED AND l.mode = 'AccessExclusiveLock') OR (NOT l.GRANTED AND l.mode = 'AccessShareLock');
```